# Menu is black and empty on new SonarQube 5.6 install

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

We do not get an issue if we install SQ5.6 on a client machine but on our Amazon servers when we fire up the server for the first time with defaults so we can install plugins, we get:

[image]

Note the black, empty menu at the top of the screen. We get this in chrome and IE11. Previous versions of SQ did not have this issue.

We have the pre-requisites correctly installed, so any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to clear cache and cookies of the browsers? does it solve the issue?

Comment: Shall we turn the server off and on again too ;) Nope. No difference.

Comment: Could you check the network requests using the [developer tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx)? I suspect that one of them fails.

Comment: Will do - also looking at installing each version from our current o0ne upwards and seeing where the issue occurs.

Comment: Further info - we experience this issue in 5.4 and above only - 5.1.2 -5.3 are fine. Feedback on any failed requests etc later today.

Comment: GET http://localhost:9000/api/l10n/index?locale= HTTP/1.1 is giving a 400 Bad Request with {"errors":[{"msg":"'' cannot be parsed as a BCP47 language tag"}]}.

Comment: @playtime222 do you confirm there is no value for parameter locale?

Comment: can you check that cookies are allowed on your browsers?

Comment: Yes, there is no value given for locale in the request.

Comment: Question withdrawn. Earlier queries from myself to the customer had apparently not been communicated clearly enough and it turns out the customer was merely using an incompatible browser, IE10. (FYI cookies were enabled and present.)

Comment: Half the team have the problem, two of us do not. 

Works with  Chrome 51.0.2704.106, Internet Explorer 11.0.32 
Fails with Firefox 45.0.1, 11.0.9

Comment: On the link in my own answer it says 'Latest' for Firefox. Can I suggest that this is changed 'Latest' to an actual version number - e.g. the value at the time of release to assist customers such as TimP?

Comment: This is actually failing in IE 11 also, even when logged in via :9000/sessions/new  the menu bar is returned empty and black.

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade to latest (Version 5.6) using yum.
2. http://localhost:9000/setup
3. Fixed!

Comment: The transition from 5.5 - 5.6 has a few breaking changes so you may be restricted to 5.5. The views/portfolio plugin is no longer available on 5.6 and if you were using the LDAP plug-in for MS Active Directory, you will have to keep that on < 1.5.1.

Answer (score -1):

It does help if the browser being used is actually listed as compatible on the SonarQube site :D

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements

Comment: Same behaviour on IE 11, Firefox latest, Chrome latest. Failing and succeeding for members of the same team in the same office on the same versions of IE and Chrome. Works for some and not others. No clues in browser or server logs.

Comment: Wow! Thought it was just us!

Comment: We are having this problem with 5.5